# PHP exec() not execute c++ program when executed via browser

Tags: php, c++, exec, praat

I have a PHP script that calls exec() to execute a c++ program but when I call it from the browser it doesn't work.
Instead if I use command-line "php5 ./mypage.php" it works.

This is my PHP page:

`<?php
    exec("./praat ./FeaturesExtraction.praat ./emotion.wav ./output/"); 
 ?>`

Praat is a program to analyse speech.
This program take as input a script FeaturesExtraction.praat and a wav emotion.wav and write the output in the directory "output" (that has all the permission).

I've tested two Web Servers, Apache and Lighttpd, but I've no results.

Someone can help me?
How can I solve this problem?
Or how can I wrap praat to use it from web?

Thanks.

Comment: Could be a permissions issue. The web server runs as a different user... Did you get any type of error output?

Comment: No errors if I run it via Web, I tried also with command-line "php5 ./mypage.php" with www-data user and it works in Lighttpd; instead in another server with apache I've this error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MelderError'
Aborted

Comment: Some news:
In localhost with lighttpd a my simple test binary in C that write a file works also via web.
In another server with Apache this binary doesn't work.
So:
- praat never works via web;
- my simple binary only works on localhost with lighttpd server.

Answer (score 0):

the problem could be "./praat". Try using the full path to the executable or do the php equivalent of chdir() to the appropriate directory

Comment: Nope, also inserting the full path it doesn't work.
I tried with another simple binary of mine written in C (it simple write a file) and it works.
I've started thinking there are some problems only with praat... but if it's true, why dose it works using command-line "php5 ./mypage.php"?
How can I see possible errors?
If I wanted to give up with php solution how could I use praat from web?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: EDIT: with my simple binary works via web only on Lighttpd but not on the Apache server... maybe some permissions errors?

Answer (score 0):

After different test this is my conclusion:
I solved the permissions problems so my simple C binary works but unfortunately praat not.
I saw apache log file and the error is:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MelderError'
Aborted

So I'll open another appropriate question:
[Error executing praat from PHP: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MelderError' Aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295793/error-executing-praat-from-php-terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of)

Thanks to everyone.