# Error executing praat from PHP: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MelderError' Aborted

Tags: php, praat

I have a PHP script that calls exec() to execute PRAAT, a c++ program, but when I call it from the browser it doesn't work. Instead if I use command-line "php5 ./mypage.php" it works.

This is my PHP page:

Praat is a program to analyse speech. This program take as input a script FeaturesExtraction.praat and a wav emotion.wav and write the output in the directory "output" (that has all the permissions).

Looking apache log this is the error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MelderError'
Aborted

How I can solve this problem? :S

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

This was finally fixed in version 5.4.15. The problem was that Praat attempted to write to its [preferences directory](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/preferences_directory.html), which is located under the user's `home`. This would of course run into problems when the user was `www-data` or the like, who don't normally *have* a home directory.

From the changelog:

> 5.4.15 (1 August 2015)
>
> - Introduced several command line options that make it easier to call Praat from a web server.

The options are documented [in the manual](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Scripting_6_9__Calling_from_the_command_line.html), under the heading "Calling Praat from a web server". The relevant option is `--no-pref-files`.

---

#### Original answer

This exact same problem came up on the mailing list some time ago: [MelderError when running as Apache](http://uk.groups.yahoo.com/group/praat-users/message/5962).

The sender of that email reported this problem existing in version 5.3.16, but not in 5.2.17. This was recognised as a possible bug, but the [changelog](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/What_s_new_.html) of the following versions do not seem to address this specifically.

What version are you using? See if this is fixed in a more recent version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution is using praat 5.1.25. 
You can download from this url:
http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-10.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/praat_5.1.25-1_amd64.deb.html