# Error executing a program using system() from PHP: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'

Tags: php, apache, exception

Here is a piece of code in my index.php

```
<?php
/*cmd is a program wittern by another people that I do not know much*/
$cmd="absolutePath/cmd";
$ret=0;
system($cmd,$ret);
?>
<p id="return"><?php echo $ret?></p>
```

If I just exec the program in command line like this: `$ absolutePath/cmd` 
and then `echo $?` I get 0, which is correct

if I exec the index.php in command line like this: `php -f index.php`
I get `<p id="return">0</p>` in the output, which is correct.

However if I open the web page in browser(both chrome and IE),
I get `<p id='return'>134</p>` and the error message:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
>   what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid Aborted

the problem looks same with this one I found on stackoverflow:
[Error executing praat from PHP: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MelderError' Aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295793/error-executing-praat-from-php-terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of) while the exception throwed is different.

Comment: What are you smoking? Your tags have no relevance to the question...

Comment: sorry,They are the tags of my last question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on the [PHP System docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php), System(command, return_var):

**If the return_var argument is present, then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable.**

So, the return status is 134. Exit statuses after 128, ie., 128+n where n is a small positive number usually mean that the program crashed with signal 'n'. so, it is signal 6. According to [this link](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl7_signal.htm), Signal 6 means 'Abort signal'.

So, my guess is, the external program `$cmd` may not be run from a browser.

Comment: It turns out that the reason is that the www-data user didn't have the env variable $HOME.